# How to write data to a JSON data file?

Tags: objective-c, json, database, nsdictionary

I am pretty new to Xcode and objective-C, so excuse me if this is incredibly easy. I am working with a a dictionary from a JSON database, and I want to fill in a database element called "age" for a person. The data in the JSON file looks like this:

{

```
"firstName":"Debra",
"lastName":"Palmer",
"middleInitial":"A",
"firstNameFirst":"Debra A. Palmer",
"lastNameFirst":"Palmer, Debra A.",
"age":""
```

}

This is my code:

```
      for(NSMutableDictionary *person in _contactsArray1)
        {
            if([person[@"firstNameFirst"] isEqual: _fullName] && [person[@"age"] isEqual: @""])
            {
                person[@"age"] = _ageString;
                // send age data to the dictionary, I get an error saying
                // Error: Expected method to write dictionary element not found on object type of NSDictionary
            }
            else if ([person[@"firstNameFirst"] isEqual: _fullName] && ![person[@"age"] isEqual: @""])
            {

            }
        }
```

This is my code for loading the JSON Data now:

```
       NSString *filePath1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"contacts" ofType:@"json"];

    // Load the file into an NSData object called JSONData

    NSError *error1 = nil;

    NSMutableData *JSONData1 = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath1 options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error1];

    // Create an Objective-C object from JSON Data

    _contactsArray1 = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:JSONData1
                  options:0
                  error:
```

Comment: You can't modify values in an immutable `NSDictionary`. You need a mutable dictionary. Show the code where you load the data (`_contactsArray1`) from the JSON data.

Comment: It seems that making it mutable got rid of the error. But now I have another issue. when the code runs, it stops it and says:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: There's no need to make `JSONData1` mutable. You want `_contactsArray1` and its subcontainers to be mutable. Do this by passing`NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to the `options:` parameter of the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method.

Comment: Thank you so much, that seems to have fixed my errors and the program runs. However the new data is not being written to the JSON file... I can try to figure this part out on my own-- but of course any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: Nothing about the code you posted is related to saving the data back to a JSON file. That's an entirely separate step.